# Overflow to change next element in a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, buffer-overflow

I have a struct setup like this:

```
typedef struct _aStruct
{
char aChar[32];
int target;
}
```

What value would make this overflow `aChar`, to change 'target'?

```
memset(aStruct.aChar,0,32)
```

I'm sorry if this question is fundamentally flawed, I am new to this.

Comment: Replace 32 with a bigger number 33 .. 36.  Any larger and you'll do damage to things outs ide the structure.

Comment: Can someone tell me, why on stack integer is above char array, why can't it be below array(then buffer overflow will not overwrite int variable). Are there any rules regarding the alignment of variables in struct?

Answer (score 1):

A big issue is that the padding on `structs` is implementation-defined. What will work on one compiler will cause segfaults or corrupted memory on another. All that can be said is that a value of 32 or less will *never* overflow, and a value of 32 + `sizeof(int)` or less will not corrupt other memory, even if it does overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the syntax, maybe you make a pointer and don't use it like a pointer.

Your typedef does not have a name, you have to make it like following :

```
typedef  struct _aStruct
{
    char aChar[32];
    int target;
}        typedef_name;
```

You have to declare a variable like this :

```
typedef_name structVar;
```

And use it like this :

```
memset(structVar.aChar, 0, 32);
```

You also can declare it as a pointer, as following :

```
typedef_name *structVar;
```

And use it like this :

```
memset(structVar->aChar, 0, 32);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, let's just assume the code works.  What I was wondering is at compile time, is there a value entered to memset that will alter other data?

Comment: If the memory where you try to write is not allocated (or does not exist statically), you will have a segmentation fault. It depends what you want your memset does.Here, you just write into your 32 sized array with 32 times '0', so it should work.

Comment: And it will not replace or alter the other things in your structure. This is not an union.